# Regex for starting with character and rest all are digits

Tags: magento-1.9, php, regex

I want a regex of length 13 in which starting word is a alphabet and rest 12   entries are digit. Something like this : A123456789764

Comment: hello @suragr have tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern `[a-fA-F]{1}[0-9]{12}` to match your scenario.

You can get idea from [tutorialpoints](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm) and [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078669/php-help-writing-regex) about how regexp is work.
for php [you can check this also](https://regex101.com/).

For live editor you can use [regexp live](https://regex101.com/)

Hope it will be helpful.